# Read from Redis slave node using Jedis

Tags: redis, jedis

I have a Redis cluster and using Java `Jedis` library to perform read/write. In my use case, I won't mind reading from slave if there is any issue with master node.

So far I haven't found any way to read from slave node using `Jedis APIs`. Is there any other option available? Like connecting to the slave node directly and then fetching the value?

Or, changing the library the only way forward?